# Syntax error in SQL statement of PL/pgSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, naming-conventions, plpgsql

I have written a stored procedure with the help of the SO community. I have cobbled/hacked together the answers of various questions to write my function.

However, when I try to create my function in the db (PostgreSQL 8.4), I get the following errors:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$4"
LINE 1: ...ank() OVER (ORDER BY  $1 ,  $2 ) /  $3 )::int as  $4  , $1 ,...
                                                            ^
```

**AND**

```
QUERY:   SELECT ceil(rank() OVER (ORDER BY  $1 ,  $2 ) /  $3 )::int as  $4  , $1 ,  $2 ,  $5 ,  $6 ,  $7 ,  $8 ,  $9 ,  $10  FROM foobar WHERE  $2  BETWEEN  $11  AND  $12  AND  $1  = ANY( $13 ) ORDER BY  $1 ,  $2 ,  $4 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "custom_group" near line 9
```

This is the code for the function I am trying to create:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_group(start_date DATE, end_date DATE, grouping_period INTEGER, _ids int[] DEFAULT '{}')
RETURNS TABLE (
grp INTEGER,
id INTEGER, 
entry_date DATE,
pop REAL,
hip REAL,
lop REAL,
pcl REAL,
vop BIGINT,
poi BIGINT) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

IF _ids <> '{}'::int[] THEN -- excludes empty array and NULL
    RETURN QUERY 
                    SELECT ceil(rank() OVER (ORDER BY id, entry_date) / $3)::int as grp
                          ,id, entry_date, pop, hip, lop, pcl, vop, poi
                    FROM   foobar
                    WHERE  entry_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date AND id = ANY(_ids)
                    ORDER  BY id, entry_date, grp ;

ELSE
    RETURN QUERY 
                    SELECT ceil(rank() OVER (ORDER BY id, entry_date) / $3)::int as grp
                          ,id, entry_date, pop, hip, lop, pcl, vop, poi
                    FROM   foobar
                    WHERE  entry_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
                    ORDER  BY id, entry_date, grp ;

END IF;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can anyone understand why I am getting these errors - and how do I fix them?

Comment: I happened to remember that I had encountered such cryptic error messages in the past, and I manage to resolve that by using different field names for the output table. I applied the same 'hack' this time and I was able to create the function with no errors. However, since I can't seem to locate this behaviour in the docs, I am guessing it's a hack - and I'll wait till someone who actually knows the reason for this odd behaviour to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from a **naming conflict**.

The variable `grp` is defined implicitly by the `RETURNS TABLE` clause. In the function body, you try to use the same identifier as column alias, which conflicts.

Just use a different name for `grp` - the column alias will not be visible outside of the function anyway.

And **table-qualify** the other columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_group(_start_date DATE
                                       ,_end_date DATE
                                       ,_grouping_period INTEGER, 
                                       ,_ids int[] DEFAULT '{}')
RETURNS TABLE (grp int, id int, entry_date date, pop real, hip real,
               lop real, pcl real, vop bigint, poi bigint) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

IF _ids <> '{}'::int[] THEN -- excludes empty array and NULL
    RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT ceil(rank() OVER (ORDER BY f.id, f.entry_date) / $3)::int AS _grp
          ,f.id, f.entry_date, f.pop, f.hip, f.lop, f.pcl, f.vop, f.poi
    FROM   foobar f
    WHERE  f.entry_date BETWEEN _start_date AND _end_date AND id = ANY(_ids)
    ORDER  BY f.id, f.entry_date, _grp;

ELSE
    RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT ceil(rank() OVER (ORDER BY f.id, f.entry_date) / $3)::int -- no alias
          ,f.id, f.entry_date, f.pop, f.hip, f.lop, f.pcl, f.vop, f.poi
    FROM   foobar f
    WHERE  f.entry_date BETWEEN _start_date AND _end_date
    ORDER  BY f.id, f.entry_date, 1; -- ordinal pos. instead of col alias
END IF;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The reason why I prefix `IN` parameters with `_` is the same: avoid such naming conflicts.

You don't even have to use an alias for the computed column at all in this case. You could use the ordinal position in `ORDER BY` like I demonstrate in the second query. I quote the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> Each expression can be the name or ordinal number of an output column
>   (SELECT list item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from
>   input-column values.

Comment: +1 for the tip on leading underscores on inbound parameters to avoid naming conflicts.